# How to store all of the object states in array state in React?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks

I have these states:

```
const [idHolder, setIdHolder] = useState([]);

  const [addedId, setAddedId] = useState({
    mainId: null,
    mainTypeId: null,
  });
```

I set the idHolder with

```
setIdHolder(addedId);
```

addedId updates itself whenever a new item added. I want to keep all created objects in the idHolder array but it only keeps the current addedId object as you can see here:

[image: terminal]

**it shows previous because of console.log

How can I keep all of the objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
setIdHolder(prev => [...prev, addedId]);
```

In the current code, you are constantly updating the whole state object.

In my code, I am using the function setter.